# ayuda con funciones y subfunciones

Tags: c++, funciones

Tengo un problema con funciones y subfunciones. Necesito cambiar dentro de la subfuncion `Seleccion()` el valor de `0x28` y que vaya pasando de valores, luego por `0x29` y `0x30` sin crear subfunciones parecidas.

```
#define 0x28
#define 0x29
#define 0x30

void Seleccion (void);

int main (void){
                while(1){
                Seleccion();}
               }

void Seleccion (void)
{A= **0X28** + 0X20}
```

Comment: ¿Qué estás tratando de hacer?

Comment: ¿Qué es una subfunción?